# How to iterate an Ember.PromiseArray in a controller

Tags: ember.js

How do you find a record in a hasMany relationship on another model? I'm probably overcomplicating things but here's a short example.

Two models, `user` and `playlist` — users can favorite playlists.

I want to change the favorite button to allow users to 'unfavorite'. To do that I need to check if the current playlist model (which I have on the playlist route) is in the user.favoritePlaylist array (to change a favorite button).

This works and automatically resolves in playlist.hbs:

```
{{#each playlist in user.playlistFavorites}}{{playlist.title}}{{/each}}
```

But in my controller the same property is unresolved because it's an Ember.PromiseArray, as far as I can tell. How do I tell if the user already favorited that playlist?

The models look like this:

````
// models/user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    playlists: DS.hasMany('playlist', {async: true }),
    favoritePlaylists: DS.hasMany('playlist', { inverse: null, async: true })
});

// models/playlist.js

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    tracks: DS.hasMany('track', { async: true }),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user', { inverse: 'playlists' })
});```
````

I attempted some pseudo code here without luck.

```
isFavorite: function() {
    var playlist = this.get('model');
    var userFavs = this.get('auth.user.favoritePlaylists');
    if (userFavs.contains(playlist) {
        // playlist already a favorite
    }
}.property('model', 'auth.user')
```

The playlist router is generated by Ember.  I have an initializer named 'auth' where I set the 'user' property to the user model once logged in so I can do `this.get('auth.user')` on the playlist controller. The auth initializer is set to run `after: 'store'` and is injected into every route and controller.

Comment: Would you mind adding the route/controller/template?  I'm trying to wrap my head around context here.  Creating an example from one of the templates here (http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info) would be even better

Comment: Thank you, added a note on the router, controller and how I access the user via my 'auth' initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `favoritePlaylist` is async you're computed property will need to update as the async property updates.  You can watch as the favoritePlaylists updates (records are added or removed) which will allow it to update as the relationship updates asynchronously.

```
isFavorite: function() {
    var playlist = this.get('model');
    var userFavs = this.get('auth.user.favoritePlaylists');
    return userFavs.contains(playlist);
}.property('model', 'auth.user.favoritePlaylists.[]')
```

Comment: Thank you, very close now. However I need to do a check if the favorites actually exist before iterating. I attached a working example. How would I write it shorter/better? Can you avoid the conditional check?

http://pastie.org/9593837